# Cipher AES, no error exception, but init not works

Tags: android, encryption, try-catch-finally

i try to cipher but my outputs after "cipher.init" won't output. Also no exceptions..and I don't know why...(new on android)

```
public void login() {
        LoginData loginData = this.fragmentBox.getUpdatedLoginData();

        String finishString = new String();
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            byte[] output = null;

            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(
                    Globals.ENCRYPTPW.getBytes(), "AES");

            System.out.println(secretKey.getEncoded().toString() +  "----" + Globals.ENCRYPTPW);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            output = cipher.doFinal(loginData.getPassword().getBytes());

            byte[] encryptedUsernameString = Base64.encode(output, 0);
            finishString = new String(encryptedUsernameString, "UTF-8");

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            Log.v("Fehler im Code","");
        } catch(Exception e){}


        System.out.println("Code: " + finishString);
}
```

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see where that data is lost? Or does `init` throw an exception?

Comment: yeah, the data never lost everything works fine till cipher.init. after that, it goes outta the try-block and calls my last line (system.out...). Output on the end is "", cause the lines after cipher.init was not called.

Comment: In the `catch(Exception e)` block, print out the stack trace to see what you're getting. I bet it's a NPE.

Comment: Now I debugged with breakpoints..and after that it springs to InvalidKeyException - but already no output (I have to see my output on this exception right?)

Comment: `Invalid key` exception is firing.. :/

Comment: Ok but why I don't see a exception on logcat? I have to stop there right? But nothing will stop..?

Comment: Try your code with only the first 16 bytes of your key. There may be several restrictions to using the `AES` algorithm, such as key lengths.

Comment: Ok. here my problem. I've tried it with 16 bytes of my key - at the first time it was not working - but after i edit it (deleted special characters - it was working) - My key for this is 32 characters long and has a mix of all characters on utf-8. So whats the solution herefore . I've also add the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6....and: I'm on mac.

Comment: Ok. i tried now again..and it works with evry 16 bytes key....I think I don't have installed the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6 on the right way....hmm..i try it again

Comment: No i got this error: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.

Comment: I've already copied the files to lib/security but it won't work....do I have to anyhting yet?...